# UDP payload length and packet transmission

Tags: networking, header, udp, packet, payload

I have data 1245 MB for trasmission via UDP over IPv4. 
For calculation of expected number of packet transmission from A to B then B relay to C, if the data transmitted in blocks of size 320bytes (i.e; payload = 320bytes), and header is 20 bytes, do we minus 20 from 320 or add in?

```
For instance, 
1245MB = 1305477120 bytes
Total UDP Payload = 320 - 20 or 320 + 20?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packet consists of:

- the IP header (20 bytes)
- the UDP header (8 bytes)
- your payload (320 bytes).

Total: 348 bytes.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to advise if my calculation for expected number of packet is correct?

Comment: If I was given an assumption that protocol overhead of UDP IPv4 is 42 bytes, the packet total will be IP header (42 bytes) + UDP header (8 bytes) + payload (320 bytes) = 370 bytes?

Comment: @user23 The protocol overhead of IPv4 UDP is 28 bytes, as I have already stated above. Not 42. I don't see any point in answering questions based on false premisses. I am not going to check your arithmetic either.

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the number of packets you don't need to take into account the size of the transport or network layer headers.  You specified a payload size of 320 bytes, which is well within the maximum size of a UDP payload without fragmentation.

Each time you call send() or sendto(), this will create a datagram (packet), so the math is simply dividing the total size by your 320 byte chunks:

1305477120 / 320 = 4079616 packets

As a side point, if you were to make your UDP payload larger, that would reduce the total number of packets.  On a lot of networks, the MTU is 1500 bytes, so you can send:

*1500 bytes - IP header (20 bytes) - UDP header (8) bytes = 1472 bytes for payload*

As a second side point, if your UDP payload is too big, i.e. payload + IP/UDP headers exceeds the MTU, then your single call to send() would result in multiple IP fragment packets.

Comment: Thanks, Joel for the explanation. If I were to send 1305477120 from A to B then B relay to C, can I assume the total number of packets will be 4079616 * 2 = 8159232. And will the calculation be different for TCP packet transmission?

Comment: You're correct that when B receives the datagrams destined for it and creates new datagrams destined for C, with the data from A, 4079616 new datagrams will be sent (assuming the same payload size of 320 bytes is used).  Now if you were to send the same amount of data over TCP, it will be a very different situation.  TCP is a stream based protocol and treats all data submitted via send() as part of that stream.  How it packetizes the stream in IP packets can very, but generally TCP will try and segment the stream into MTU (also called maximum segment) sized packets.